# How could I group attributes values in a category in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, collections, product

I've created a custom attribute in Magento, called 'brand_name' and 'brand_id'

I need in each categories, to show all the "brands" available for this categories.

Example:

I've a Shoes category, in my Shoes category I've products with brand name like 'Louboutin' 'Dior' etc...

I'd like to show in a page those brand, then when clicking on it I'd like to show all product which are from "Louboutin" in category "Shoes"

The last part is simpler I think, however I don't really know how to start but I'm pretty sure Magento provides such functionnality.

Do you know which method could I use to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have cut and paste for you from [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v../viewthread/214172/#t286462):

Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes.

Select brand_name

At the bottom make sure Used for Sorting in Product Listing is set to Yes. <- your design theme must support it.

Then over in Catalog -> Manage Categories, select your category that displays your product listing, select the Display Settings tab.

brand_name should be one of the items in the Available Product Listing Sort by multi select. Go down to the next field Default Product Listing sort by, uncheck Use Config Settings and set the dropdown to brand_name.

To make the system default for product listings be sorted by brand_name, go into System -> Configuration -> Catalog ->Frontend and set Product Listing Sort by dropdown to brand_name. Then you can leave the “Use Config Settings” checkbox in Manage Categories checked